# Given two matrices, prove that their product is identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We are given two matrices: $A=[a_{ij}]$ and cofactor $B_{ji} = (-1)^{i+j} \frac{\det A_{ij}}{\det A} $. Prove that then $A \cdot B = I$.

I know that $(AB)_{ki} = \sum _j a_{kj}b_j =  \sum _j a_{kj} (-1)^{i+j} \frac{\det A_{ij}}{\det A}$.

When $k=i$, we have $ \sum _j a_{kj} (-1)^{i+j} \frac{\det A_{ij}}{\det A}= \frac{\det A_{ij}}{\det A} =1$.

But I don't know what to do for $k \neq i$.

Could you help me?

Comment: I don't have time to write a hint, but the only thing that can happen in $(AB)_{ki}$ is the signs causing cancellation. So if I were you, I'd factor out $\frac{1}{\det A}$ and look for cancellation from the alternating signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_{rj}$ denote the matrix obtained from the $(n\times n)$-matrix $A$ by deleting  ${\rm row}_r(A)$ and ${\rm col}_j(A)$, and pushing the remains together. Then "expanding $\det(A)$ with respect to ${\rm row}_r(A)$" means the formula
$$\det(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{r+j} a_{rj}\det(A_{r,j})\ .\tag{1}$$
Assume now that $s\ne r$ and that $A'$ denotes the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing ${\rm row}_r(A)$ bei ${\rm row}_s(A)$. Then $A'_{rj}=A_{rj}$ for all $j$. Since $A'$ has two equal rows we get
$$0=\det(A')=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{r+j} a_{sj}\det(A_{r,j})\ .\tag{2}$$

We now introduce the matrix $B$ with $$b_{jr}:=(-1)^{r+j}{\det(A_{r,j})\over\det(A)}\ .$$
Then
$$\sum_{j=1}^n  a_{sj}b_{jr}={1\over\det(A)}\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{r+j} a_{sj}\det(A_{r,j})\ ,$$
and here the right side is $=1$ if $s=r$ by $(1)$, and $=0$ if $s\ne r$ by $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it is the same as the laplace's formula just in the different direction.
This is called cramers rule und gives you the inverse of a Matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to prove that? The proff on Wikipedia looks pretty time-consuming :)

Answer (score 0):

The same argument for $k \ne i$ just gives you a new matrix $A'$ on the numerator instead of $A$.  If you think about it, the $i$th row of $A'$ is equal to the $k$th row of $A$, so...

Comment: So the result would be that detA' =0, and we would get indentity matrix,, but I don't quite understand why the rows are equal...

Comment: @Hagrid In that case I must ask how you know that you get $1$ when $k=i$.